Getting error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=6: Service Unavailable
I am trying to pull image from Azure ACR from one of vm where docker is installed. This was working before without any issue. But now i am getting error while pulling the image from Azure ACR.
Error message : error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=6: Service unavailable.
Note: Pull image was working before this issue occur.
Anybody any help on this strange issue !!
I have tried restarting docker client and vm still didn't work. I have checked network connectivity between the docker client vm and Azure ACR, it is fine.
Note : I have tried pushing the image to the same Azure ACR, it is working but getting error while pull the image.


Verify ACR Service Availability
• Ensure that the Azure ACR service is operational in the Azure region where your registry is hosted. Check the Azure status page:
Azure Status (https://status.azure.com/)
• If there are ongoing outages in your region, this could be the cause.

Check ACR Permissions
• Ensure the credentials used for pulling the image have the correct permissions.
◦ If using a service principal, confirm it has the AcrPull role assigned.
◦ If using a managed identity, check its assigned roles.
• Verify credentials by running:If it logs in successfully, credentials are likely not the issue.
az acr login --name <ACR_NAME>

Validate Image Existence
• Confirm that the image and tag you are trying to pull exist in the Azure ACR:Example:
az acr repository show-tags --name myacr --repository myimage
az acr repository show-tags --name <ACR_NAME> --repository <IMAGE_NAME>

Check Docker Daemon Logs
• Inspect Docker logs for additional details on the error:Look for any errors or network-related issues during the pull operation.
sudo journalctl -u docker

Clear Docker Cache
• Sometimes, Docker's cache can interfere with operations. Clear the cache:
docker system prune -a

Pull the Image Manually with Debugging
Enable detailed output during the pull operation: 
docker --debug pull <ACR_NAME>.azurecr.io/<IMAGE_NAME>:<TAG>
This structured approach should help identify and resolve the problem effectively.


